# Is it possible to reposition/recreate annotations in the relayout event handler?

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I have a plot where the data is dynamically generated anytime the user pans or zooms (other things cause re-generation of data too).

When this happens it's often the case that the points in the new data set aren't exactly the same as the points in the new set.

Our users can click on a point to add an annotation at that data point.

When we generate the new data set this leaves the annotations pointing to the wrong places. They point to data that doesn't exist anymore. Sometimes it's only a small variation in X. Othertimes it's a much larger variation in Y and then the annotation seems to be floating, completely disconnected.

I put a post on the Plotly community forum with some pictures: https://community.plotly.com/t/reposition-annotations-on-relayout/75753

I'd like to be able to reposition the annotations on relayout. Find the closest new point to the annotation's old point and re-anchor it there. Either by updating the annotation, or just removing it and creating a new one.

The problem is that I create the annotations in the click event handler where I have access to the data point and the X and Y axis objects. This is how I know where to position the annotation. Something like:

```
let point = evt.points[0];
let newAnnotation = {
  x: point.xaxis.d2l(point.x),
  y: point.yaxis.d2l(point.y)
}
```

In the relayout handler I don't have access to the points (of course, because nothing has been clicked), so I can't access the `xaxis.d2l` function to do the positioning for me.

It is possible to get a reference to the axis objects so I can call `d2l`? Or is this the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: You could create a variable, say `d2l`, in the outer scope of the click and relayout handlers, and which will hold the corresponding axis function. Upon first click in the handler make the assignment `if (!d2l) d2l = point.xaxis.d2l;` so that you can use it in the relayout handler as well.